# Loading Firebase into Tableview

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, tableview

I am trying to load data from Firebase into my TableView and FSCalendar. I am not sure what I am doing wrong. I think my problem may be coming from my reload but i have built them like this before and havent had problems. So if someone could read and see what is going on.

My problem is: the data from Firebase is not populating the cells in my tableview and the dots for my events are not showing up, the calendar is FScalendar. I have found in the documentation that this function will make them appear but i am not seeing them. I appreciate any help.

My Firebase Data Model:

```
{
  "calendarevents" : {
    "2021-01-12" : {
      "eventColor" : "red",
      "eventDate" : "2021-01-12",
      "eventName" : "Enrollment"
    },
    "2021-01-15" : {
      "eventColor" : "red",
      "eventDate" : "2021-01-15",
      "eventName" : "First Day"
    }
  }
}
```

My event Handler:

```
func retrieveEventsFromDatabase() {
        dbReference = Database.database().reference().child("calendarevents")
        dbReference.observe(DataEventType.value, with: { [weak self] (snapshot) in
            
            guard snapshot.childrenCount > 0 else { return }
            
            var events: [EventsDataModel] = []
            for event in snapshot.children.allObjects as! [DataSnapshot]
            {
                let object = event.value as? [String: AnyObject]
                
                let eventName = object?["eventName"]
                let eventDate = object?["eventDate"]
                let eventColor = object?["eventColor"]
                
                let event = EventsDataModel(eventName: eventName as! String, eventDate: eventDate as! String,eventColor: eventColor as! String)
 
                events.append(event)
   
            }
            
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self?.eventsTable.reloadData()
                self?.calendar.reloadData()
            }
        })      
    }
```

My Tableview and FScalendar Functions:

```
func calendar(_ calendar: FSCalendar, appearance: FSCalendarAppearance, eventDefaultColorsFor date: Date) -> [UIColor]? {
        let dateString = self.dateFormatter2.string(from: date)
        
        for data in eventsArray {
            
            if data.eventDate.contains(dateString) {
                
                if data.eventColor == "red" {
                    return [UIColor.red]
                }
                return [UIColor.black]
            }
        }
        
        return nil
        
    }
    
    func calendar(_ calendar: FSCalendar, numberOfEventsFor date: Date) -> Int {
        let dateString = self.dateFormatter2.string(from: date)
        
        for data in eventsArray {
            
            if data.eventDate.contains(dateString) {
                return 1
            }
        }
            return 0
    }

    
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        print(eventsArray.count)
        return eventsArray.count
        
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        
        let friend = eventsArray[indexPath.row].eventName
        
        let cell = eventsTable.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "eventCell", for: indexPath) as! EventsTitleTableViewCell
        
        cell.eventTitleLabel?.text = friend
         return cell
    }
}
```

View did load:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        calendar.dataSource = self
        calendar.delegate = self
        
        
        retrieveEventsFromDatabase()
        

    }
```

Comment: Have you tried printing some different values in your for-in loop within retrieveEventsFromFirebase()? For example, print(”object”). What gets printed to the console?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to have forgot to populate self.eventsArray.

Before reloading tableView, do

```
self.eventsArray = events
```